# Linter for Slack Block Kit

Tags: slack, slack-block-kit

when sending blocks to Slack some rules apply.
Currently I'm aware of two:

- hard rule - max 50 blocks in a single message (https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks)
- soft rule/hint - send a text as fallback with your blocks

I'm sure there are more rules and guidelines. Is somebody knowing a linter, which can be used to check, if my templates are valid without sending them to a real Slack space?